# Does it really inverse a transform matrix?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, transform

```
void inverse44(
double *inverse,
double *matrix
)
{
double trans[3], trans_xf[3];
MTX3_t matrix3;

inverse[0] = matrix[0];
inverse[1] = matrix[4];
inverse[2] = matrix[8];
inverse[4] = matrix[1];
inverse[5] = matrix[5];
inverse[6] = matrix[9];
inverse[8] = matrix[2];
inverse[9] = matrix[6];
inverse[10] = matrix[10];
inverse[15] = 1.0;
inverse[12] = inverse[13] = inverse[14] = 0.0;

trans[0] = matrix[3];
trans[1] = matrix[7];
trans[2] = matrix[11];

MTX4_mtx3(MTX4_cast_pc(matrix),&matrix3);
MTX3_vec_multiply_t(VEC3_cast_pc(trans),&matrix3,VEC3_cast(trans_xf));
inverse[3] = -trans_xf[0];
inverse[7] = -trans_xf[1];
inverse[11] = -trans_xf[2];
}
```

What does this function do?

MTX3_t is a definition of 3*3 matrix. MTX4_mtx3 gets a sub matrix. MTX3_vec_multiply_t multiply a vector and a matrix.

Comment: You know you can check this yourself, right?

Comment: Without some math background I don't think it's very easy to check this. I mean you can see if it "works" for a single case, or even quite a few but that's not really proof it's a valid method..

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Please see [this link](http://www.cg.info.hiroshima-cu.ac.jp/~miyazaki/knowledge/teche53.html) to compute the inverse of a transformation matrix. The basic idea is that the scaling/rotation combination of the transformation matrix (first 3x3 sub-matrix) is an orthonormal matrix and inverse of on orthonormal matrix is equal to the the transpose. So, the first part is the transpose computation. The second part (starting from the line trans[0] = matrix[3]) is the computation for the inverse for the translation part (last column of the matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will spend a little more to study it.

Answer (score 0):

This will invert a transform matrix *only* if it is a combination of rotations and translations.  It will not work correctly if the transform matrix also includes scaling or a perspective projection.

Comment: I think at that situation, the first 3x3 sub-matrix should not be a orthonormal matrix. So surely this way is wrong.

Comment: *Only* those transform matrices whose 3x3 submatrix is orthonormal, and whose fourth row is `[0 0 0 1]`, will be correctly inverted by your function -- other transform matrices will not.